# Javascript code messing with responsiveness?

Tags: javascript, menu, navigation, responsive

This javascript code ruins the responsiveness of my website. Is there anything I can do?

Without this code my site is fully reponsive (I'm using bootstrap) but this makes the section/content overlap.

```
$(function() {
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$('section').height(windowHeight);


/* checking sections position and activate corresponding navigation item */
var checkActive = function() {
    var screenCenter = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() /2;

    $('section').each(function() {
        sectionTop = $(this).offset().top;
        selectedSection = $('nav a').index($('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]'));
        console.log(selectedSection);
        if( sectionTop < screenCenter  && sectionTop + $(this).height() >= screenCenter) {
            $('nav li').eq(selectedSection).addClass('active');
        } else {

            $('nav li').eq(selectedSection).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
}

checkActive();

/* Click handling of navigation links */
$('nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dest = $(this.hash);
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $(dest).offset().top});

});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    checkActive();
})
});
```

It is used along with:

```
<nav class="vertical-fixed-nav">
<ul>
    <li class="about"><a href="#about"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li class="portfolio"><a href="#portfolio"><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li class="services"><a href="#services"><span>Work</span></a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#contact"><span>Skills</span></a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#contact1"><span>Music</span></a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#contact2"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```